# Is it possible to check if pdostatement::fetch() has results without iterating through a row?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a page which needs to check for results, and the way I came up with to do it is successful, but iterates through the first row of results. Is there a way I can check without iterating, or to go back to that first row without executing the query again?

I was doing this:

```
 $q = pdo::prepare($SQL);
 $q->execute(array(':foo'=> foo, 'bar'=>bar);
 if(!q->fetch){
     //no results;
 }else{
      //results;
 };
```

It does pretty much exactly what I hoped, with the unfortunate side affect of skipping the first row of results.

I've resorted to running $q->execute() a second time. Is there a way to avoid doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put the result of fetch into a variable:

```
if($row = $q->fetch()) {
    // $row contains first fetched row
    echo $row['coloumn_name'];
}
else
    // no results
```

Comment: The problem with doing it this way is that the if statement moves the cursor through the results by one increment - so your echo statement starts on the second row.

Comment: @inorganik: It moves the cursor by one row, but it stores the row into `$row` first. So the echo statement is echoing data from the first row, not the second row.

Comment: @Olhovsky right but presumably if you have results you will need to loop through them. When you go to use a `while` loop, it will be starting on the second row of your results.

Comment: @inorganik Ah, I see what you mean. Yes.

Comment: @inorganik: using a do-while loop should solve the problem, albeit inelegantly

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be lazy, you could always do something like:

```
$totalRows = count($resultSet->fetchAll());
```

However, this is less than efficient for large result sets.

Otherwise, see the manual [page about rowCount()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) (particularly example #2) for what appears to be the standard workaround.  There are some interesting user-supplied comments on that page as well.

Answer (score 0):

May be you'll find `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` usefull for this. See example at php.net site http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php#77984

Answer (score 0):

rowCount() is known to work with mysql, so if portability is not a concern, use that.

otherwise, you can try to change the program logic, e.g.

```
    $stmt->execute();

    $count = 0;
    foreach($stmt as $record) {
        // output...
        $count++;
    }

    if(!$count)
        echo "no results!";
```

Comment: I already have a variable similar to your $count that I'm using for other purposes, so this could be exactly what I need.