# Check for PDO Results, If None Display Message, If Yes then Loop Through

Tags: php, pdo

Trying to find another simple answer but only finding complicated examples.

I'm trying to simply query a table, if there are results to display then loop through them, if there are not then display a message - unfortunately all examples I can find 'fetch' as part of the while loop, not before, so I'm trying to do:

```
$stm = $PdoObj->prepare("SELECT * FROM NEWS_articles");
$stm ->execute();
$results = $stm ->fetch();

if($results==null){
    echo "<p>No dice, try other criteria</p>";
}else{
    foreach($results as $row){
        echo $row["articleName"];
    }
}
```

The following question is close to what I'm trying to achive but was never answered satisfactorily: [Is it possible to check if pdostatement::fetch() has results without iterating through a row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556692/is-it-possible-to-check-if-pdostatementfetch-has-results-without-iterating-t)

Comment: Apologies - I should have mentioned what's happening when I try this - I get an error saying: 
PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'articleName'

Comment: Have you debugged `$results` at all to see if it contains what you think it does?

Comment: @MrFett Be aware that though your `$results==null` is working, that is not a readable comparison considering you are actually doing `array()==null` you should consider a more syntactically correct check such as [`empty($results)`](http://uk1.php.net/empty) or `$results==array()` or `count($results)==0`

Comment: `empty($results)` is equal to `$results==null` either way in this case, so, there is no use to change one for another. Other two are correct but quite useless.

Comment: *facepalm*... `not a readable comparison` - code should be readable, comparing a variable to null explicitly like that, makes it look like it could actually be `NULL`

Comment: I know it's an old issue.  But I'm running into the same issue.  I try to check at the beginning to set a session message in html that no records were found.  Before executing the output section which is separate.  Glad it wasn't just me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need not `fetch()` but `fetchAll()`.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Your Common Sense use [`fetchAll`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php). If there aren't any results, it will return an empty array:

```
$results = $stm->fetchAll();
if(empty($results))//or  if(!$results)  or  if(count($results)==0)  or if($results == array())
{
    echo 'Nothing found';
}
else
{
    foreach($results as $result)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

The official method for getting how many rows have been returned is [`rowCount()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php):

```
$stm->execute();

if($stm->rowCount() == 0)
{
    echo 'Nothing found';
}
else
{
    //do your stuff
}
```

Though this would not be necessary if you are already calling `fetchAll` as this result can be used to determine the size of the result set.

Comment: This would be unnecessary call.

Comment: @YourCommonSense You mean to say this doesn't answer his question regarding how to find out how many results are returned??

Comment: It does, but extra call to rowCount() is useless. One don't need neither rowCount() nor a dedicated variable $rowC to know if they've got a result or not. This call makes code unnecessarily bloated.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Nevertheless it answers the question using a 'proper' method, so it certainly deserves it's place on this page. I have, however, added an alternative to just check the results of `fetchAll` if that's what *you prefer*

Comment: `empty()` is useless here *again* :) It makes me wonder, why PHP users are so inclined to extra operators, which makes code bloated with no benefit :)

Comment: @YourCommonSense What.. you'd rather the lazy `!$results` with extremely illegible assumptions being used? Not very helpful for the OP or any beginner to understand what's happening there is it..

Comment: Look what's wrong with your reasoning: You are confusing this function's purpose. `rowCount()` is used to know the `number`. But we don't actually need a *number* but only whether we have a result or not. Yet, **as we have our result already**, we don't need any extra calls. Exactly as Holy Occam told us.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'm aware of that, but considering the query regarding how many results have been returned was brough up, it is only correct to show the function that does that for future users, that have performed an `UPDATE` and therefore won't be using `fetch` functions. I have re-ordered and slightly re-worded my answer, including an additional sentence stating that `rowCount` is not needed when fetching - but it **shouldn't be removed** as it will be helpful for others. It **does not** make this answer incorrect.

Comment: Okay, but your phrasing is still unclear. **I never said** that fetchAll() have to be used to answer the question whether we have any results or not. It would be obviously wrong. I asked the OP to use fetchAll because the code logic required it. Yet it would require no other changes in the code but only 3 letters of "All". A simple shoot to solve **both** problems.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `fetch()` , use `fetchAll()`.

`fetchAll` — Returns an array containing all of the result set rows